# Resolved - Add Product Thumbnails to Custom Grid

Tags: module, magento-1, grid, product-images, thumbnail

I have created a custom module with grid. Now trying to add the product thumbnails to this grid, but the $val in renderer file is empty and images don't show up (see image below).

[![custom module grid images don't show up][1]][1]

Here is the renderer file at ....\Block\Adminhtml\Template\Grid\Renderer\Image.php

```
class Cpstest_ProductComment_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return $this->_getValue($row);
    }

    protected function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $val = str_replace("no_selection", "", $val);
        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/product/' . $val;
        $out = "<img src=". $url ." width='60px'/>";
        return $out;
    }
}
```

And the column code in Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn('image', array(
    'header'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image'),
    'align'    => 'left',
    'index'    => 'image',
    'width'    => '70',
    'renderer' => 'Cpstest_ProductComment_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_Image'
));
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the content of  `$value`? (just output this w/o img-tag)

Comment: I tried to print it out to see the value but nothing showed up.

Comment: But I think it should be the name of the thumbnail.

Comment: You can use Inspect Element in your browser, or right click the broken image then View Image Info (Firefox) or Copy image address (Chrome), to see what the image `src` is.

Comment: @subroutines I inspected the images and the URL is "http://formodulecheck.dev/media/". The $value is empty, it doesn't get the image name, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: looks like the `image` attribute hasn't been selected, check [this post](https://www.atwix.com/magento/thumbnail-images-admin-product-grid/), especially the comment section.

Comment: @bestwebdevs can please post your full code? Do you rewrite admin product grid? If yes, i'll post a new answer.

Comment: Hi @subroutines ,  I tried to follow that article and got the same result as in the image of my question. Followed the advice in comments part and got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Varien_Data_Collection::joinAttribute() in ......Grid.php

Comment: Hi @sv3n , do you need the full code for the Grid.php file? No, I guess I'm creating a brand new grid without rewriting the admin product grid.

Comment: Please post all you have (config.xml, Observer.php, Blocks) :) I'll take a look at it tomorrow .... shouln't be hard to add an image :P

Comment: Hi @sv3n , I don't have an observer. I have posted full Grid file if that will help. I know this should be something pretty easy, but I've been struggling for days already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image` attribute isn't part of your custom collection. The easiest way to display the thumbnails is changing your `render` function to something like below, which loads a product based on `productcomment_increment_id` and get its thumnail.

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getProductcommentIncrementId());
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/product/' . $product->getThumbnail();
    $out = "<img src=". $url ." width='60px'/>"; 
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: OMG @subroutines !!!! I tried dozens of different articles and codes and nothing seemed to work  for 100%. Thank you SO MUCH! I wish I could +1000  your reputation!

Comment: @bestwebdevs, glad to help:)